# can not create newline in text file

Tags: php

I write data in a txt file. However the writen data can not create new lines. Here is my code

```
<?php
$address[] = "jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999";
$address[] = "jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999";
$address[] = "jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999";
$fh=fopen("address.txt","a");
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{
    fwrite($fh,$address[$i]."\n");
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

the writen data look like this in txt file

```
jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999
```

I have tried "`\n"` at the end of fwrite, but it seems doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you're making a csv file. Are you aware of [`fputcsv()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)?

Comment: `\n` works for me. Weird.

Comment: You wont see newline with notepad but it will appear perfectly with notepad++ or any other editors

Comment: try \n\r if you are using windows notepad to open the file you created.

Comment: Your code checks out OK for me, but I'm on UNIX. If you're on Windows or MAC, use `\r\n` --- `fwrite($fh,$address[$i]."\r\n");` --- Including `\r` on UNIX will not affect anything.

Comment: Although using `fputcsv()` does fit the bill, simply renaming a file's extension to `.csv` and formatted the way OP has it now, will open up correctly in Excel. @echolocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `\n` character for new lines, which is correct for *nix-based systems. In windows it's `\r\n`. It might be different on other platforms. Use `PHP_EOL` instead. This will correctly add the newline character for the current platform.

It could also be an issue with the editor you're using to view the file. For example, Notepad will only recognize `\r\n` as a newline. In this case, you're using `\n`, so these won't be shown if you're using Notepad. The solution would be to use a correct sequence that's recognizable by Notepad, or to a use a different editor altogether (Notepad++ is good).

Comment: *"It could also be an issue with the editor you're using to view the file..."* Actually, upon testing with only `\n`, my file was written correctly and viewed with Notepad. Then again, I'm on UNIX for my server but Windows XP as my PC with Notepad; just to test. I do have Notepad++ though. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Weird. I see [many posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=notepad+doesn%27t+detect+newlines) where Notepad doesn't work with `\n` as newline characters. Windows Notepad isn't as smart as Notepad++ and skips the non-Windows end-of-line characters. I'd just use `PHP_EOL` so the script works regardless of what platform it's used on.

Comment: I think it might be newer versions of Windows and not XP. As a matter of fact, a friend of mine who's on Windows 7's Notepad, it did not open a file correctly till he changed some of the settings in it; yes... weird. You're right though about `PHP_EOL`, it's better to use.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

Thsi is the simplest method.

```
<?php
$address[] = "jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999";
$address[] = "jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999";
$address[] = "jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999";
$fh=fopen("address.txt","a");
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{
    fwrite($fh,$address[$i]."
");
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

But you can also use `\r\n` for new line or even `PHP_EOL`.

Answer (score 1):

Try PHP_EOL here is the code

```
<?php
$address[] = "jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999";
$address[] = "jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999";
$address[] = "jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999";
$fh=fopen("address.txt","a");
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{
    fwrite($fh,$address[$i].PHP_EOL);
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

and Output

```
jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999
jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999
jon smith,1234 oak st.,big city,or, 9999
```